# reorder php array using alphanumeric search

Tags: php

i have this array:

```
$final[0] = "San"
$final[1] = "Antonio"
$final[2] = "de"
$final[3] = "Areco"
$final[4] = 1200
$final[5] = 1231
$final[6] = "San"
$final[7] = "Martin"
$final[8] = "de"
$final[9] = "Andes"
$final[10] = 1200
$final[11] = 1231
$final[12] = "Carlos"
$final[13] = "Casares"
$final[14] = 1200
$final[15] = 1231
```

I need to combine all alphanumeric values into a single one and leave the numbers on a single value.

This is what i'm trying, but i can't make it work, if the names are two words long seems to work fine, but with three or more words is like i 'miss' the first one.

This is how it should look like:

```
$final[0] = "San Antonio de Areco"
$final[1] = 1200
$final[2] = 1231
$final[3] = "San Martin de Andes"
$final[4] = 1200
$final[5] = 1231
$final[6] = "Carlos Casares"
$final[7] = 1200
$final[8] = 1231
```

Can you please give me a hint?

Thanks!

```
foreach ($final as $c => $v) {

    if (ctype_alpha($v)) {

        $vuelta1 = ($c+1);

        if (ctype_alpha($final[$vuelta1])) {

            $final[$vuelta1] = $v." ".$final[$vuelta1];
            unset($final[$c]);

        } else {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with some comments in  the code.

```
<?php
$final[0] = "San";
$final[1] = "Antonio";
$final[2] = "de";
$final[3] = "Areco";
$final[4] = 1200;
$final[5] = 1231;
$final[6] = "San";
$final[7] = "Martin";
$final[8] = "de";
$final[9] = "Andes";
$final[10] = 1200;
$final[11] = 1231;
$final[12] = "Carlos";
$final[13] = "Casares";
$final[14] = 1200;
$final[15] = 1231;
$final[16] = "this";
$final[17] = "is";
$final[18] = "a";
$final[19] = "test";

$new = array(); // this will hold the reorderd values
$string_parts = array(); // temp array to store string parts to be combined

foreach ( $final as $c => $v )
{
    if(ctype_alpha($v))
    {
        $string_parts[] = $v; // this is a string, store it for later with other possible strings
    }
    else
    {
        if( count( $string_parts ) > 0 ) $new[] = implode( ' ', $string_parts ); // all the parts that were detected as strings will be combined into one value in the new array, spearated by spaces
        $string_parts = array(); // reset the array
        $new[] = $v; // not a string, then add the number to the new array
    }
}

// Fix bug spotted by IMSoP in his comment
if( count( $string_parts ) > 0 ) $new[] = implode( ' ', $string_parts ); // all the parts that were detected as strings will be combined into one value in the new array, spearated by spaces

print_r( $new );
?>
```

If you want to replace the original array with the new one:

```
<?php
$final = $new;
?>
```

Comment: -1 for not explaining what you've done and how the OP should learn from it.

Comment: This solution has a bug of its own: it won't put any strings into the new array which don't have a number after them - i.e. it loses data if the last entry in the array isn't a number.

Comment: Indeed, I guess I owe you a beer or something. Fixed in answer with test case added. Your solution is much more elegant anyway.

Comment: This is one of those problems with edge-cases every which way; my first couple of attempts to write it with a `while` rather than `foreach` accidentally dropped me into infinite loops!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.  it does fill a different array but should accomplish what you are looking for.

```
$aNew = array();  // the new array
$wasAlpha = 0;  // just a boolean toggle

foreach($final as $v){
    if(is_int($v)){
        $wasAlpha = 0;  // toggle flag
        $aNew[] = $v;   // push the number onto the new array
    }else{
        if($wasAlpha){  // last one was also not a number
            $aNew[sizeof($aNew)-1] .= ' ' . $v;  // append to last with a space
        }else{
            $wasAlpha = 1; // last one was a number
            $aNew[] = $v;  // push new non number value to new array
        }
    }
}
```

edit:  you may prefer `is_numeric()`

Comment: What's with `0` and `1` for booleans? And `sizeof`? I'm guessing you've come from a C background?

Comment: it was just a fast solution, there is likely a better way.  you prefer `count()`?  I prefer `array.length` lol

Comment: Yeah, `count` is the standard name in PHP, `sizeof` is an alias that will be unfamiliar and confusing to some; and we have real booleans `true` and `false`. Also, `is_numeric` is often not a good choice, because it considers strings like `3.5e10` as "numeric".

Comment: syntax.  `count` and `sizeof` are synonymous. all of the entries in the question were integers, so I used `is_int` in the answer.  I just put the edit in in case.  You could eliminate the need for the boolean all together by checking the value in the last key of the original array, but I think this is less overhead.

Comment: Yeah, it's a case of coding style; `sizeof` might be familiar to those with other backgrounds, but might also be misconstrued by them (it's quite different in meaning from in C, for instance). It wasn't a major criticism, but a "fluent" PHP coder would probably use `count` and `true` rather than `sizeof` and `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this very simple logic:

```
<?php
        $final[0] = "San";
        $final[1] = "Antonio";
        $final[2] = "de";
        $final[3] = "Areco";
        $final[4] = 1200;
        $final[5] = 1231;
        $final[6] = "San";
        $final[7] = "Martin";
        $final[8] = "de";
        $final[9] = "Andes";
        $final[10] = 1200;
        $final[11] = 1231;
        $final[12] = "Carlos";
        $final[13] = "Casares";
        $final[14] = 1200;
        $final[15] = 1231;

        $tempArr = array();
        $temp_val = '';
        $count = 0;




        foreach ($final as $Val) {
            if (!is_numeric($Val)) {
                $temp_val.= $Val . " ";
            } else {
                if (!empty($temp_val)) {

                    // Assign String 
                    $tempArr[$count] = $temp_val;
                    $temp_val = '';
                    $count++;

                    // Assign Number
                    $tempArr[$count] = $Val;
                    $count++;
                } else {

                    $tempArr[$count] = $Val;
                    $count++;
                }
            }
        }



        var_dump($tempArr);
        ?>
```

Very easy & fast execute code:

Answer (score 0):

Although you've called it `$final`, you're using the same variable for both the array you're looping over, and the re-formatted version. This is almost always a bad idea, and rarely works as expected.

If you dump out `$v` each time round the loop, you will see that PHP is still using the original values of the array rather than the changes you've applied as you loop through it. So after `'San Antonio'` gets glued together, the loop goes on to `'Antonio'` in the original array, and the `'San'` is lost forever.

The better approach will be to build a new array with the elements re-formatted as you want, as others have suggested. Here's another version, using a nested `while` loop rather than a `foreach`, to "look ahead" for string entries to concatenate ([Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JTequ4)):

```
$really_final = array();
$k = 0;
while ( $k < count($final) )
{
    // Take the value of the next entry regardless
    $v = $final[$k];
    // Move to next entry
    $k++;

    // If it's a string, look ahead until you find a non-string
    if ( ctype_alpha($v) )
    {
        while ( $k < count($final) && ctype_alpha($final[$k]) )
        {
            // append the next string
            $v .= ' ' . $final[$k];
            // Move to next entry
            $k++;
        }
    }

    // Add to the new array
    $really_final[] = $v;
}
```

Comment: Why going with two loops isn't that O(N^2)

Comment: @Omiga No, because they're not actually independent loops, they're both updating the same counter. The inner loop is performing a kind of fast-forward until it reaches a non-string item, at which point it hands control back to the outer loop. (I was concentrating mostly on explaining why the OP's code was failing, to be honest, which nobody else bothered to do.)

Comment: The ugliest part of this is the need for the `if` as well as the `while`, but I couldn't get my head round where to increment the counter if I combined them.

Comment: yes, you right, but the increment may work for if (is_numeric($final[$k+1]) continue;